# MySQL - LEFT JOIN doesn't return while CPU at 100%

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a problem where I'm trying to use an LEFT JOIN statement in my query but it doesn't return anything. I have tried both an INNER and a RIGHT JOIN which works.
But the problem with INNER and RIGHT is that they will just skip the row where the Clause isn't  matched which I don't like.

And as the title also says, while making the query the CPU load is at 100% with the LEFT JOIN statement.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.name, t1.name guid, t1.timestamp, t1.server_id, t1.message
FROM chat t1
LEFT JOIN players t2 ON t2.guid = t1.name
ORDER by t1.id DESC 
LIMIT 0,20;
```

Result from EXPLAIN:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows   Extra
1  SIMPLE      t1    ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 37302  Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      t2    ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 610715
```

Comment: Please post the result of `EXPLAIN` for the problematic query.

Comment: does t2 or t1 have any indexes at all?

Comment: Yes, both t2.guid and t1.name is indexed. The result that i posted was from an RIGHT JOIN... :/ So i have made another update now with the correct result

Comment: I have also tried to force the use of the keys, but without any effect.
INNER and RIGHT join enables the keys for some reason :/